# Setting multiple JPanels to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I need to format my multiple panels into my main panel, however I'm troubled with which layout to use and more so on how to do it with a specific layout.

The layout I need is like this

[image]

So far the code I have is this:

```
public TDPanel(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150,800));
    this.setBackground(Color.gray);
    this.tdWorld = towerOfDefenses;
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

game = new JPanel();
game.setBackground(Color.blue);
game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

textBox = new JTextField();
textBox.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
textBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));

menuPanel = new JPanel();
menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,800));
menuPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

this.add(game);
this.add(textBox);
this.add(menuPanel);
}
```

I would appreciate any help given!

Comment: Will the GUI be resizable and if so, how is the extra space assigned?

Comment: BTW - I'd probably use [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for that GUI.

Comment: I see a `BorderLayout`, maybe a `GridLayout` or `JSplitPane` or `GridBagLayout`

Comment: The GUI can be resizable, and thx for the suggestion!

Comment: I see a `GridBagLayout` or a `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine at least 3 `BorderLayout`s. Why? Because the component you put in `CENTER` will be maximized and for the others you can set a static width (or height) and don't have to do further configuration to get the desired behaviour.

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| BorderLayout.CENTER (1) | BorderLayout.EAST (2) |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

In (1) you put the game panel (3) and the "game controls" (4):

```
+-------------------------+
| BorderLayout.CENTER (3) |
+-------------------------+
| BorderLayout.SOUTH (4)  |
+-------------------------+
```

If you want the text field and the button in (4) to have the same size and maximized (width) then use a `GridLayout`, othewise you can use `FlowLayout` to have them layed out with some space after it. But what I recommend doing here is the same as for the game and menu panel in (2): use a `BorderLayout` and put the component you want to be maximized in the center.

You could use more sophisticated LayoutManagers like `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout` but it is not really needed for this simple layout (guess it's a matter of taste).

Comment: sorry, could you explain more on the 3 borderlayouts and how would I create the 3 different layouts?

Comment: Yes, I didn't say it explicitly, but you can use just plain JPanels and only set the LayoutManager for (1) to (4), then in there you put your original panels.

Answer (score -1):

First,I recommend you use **Swing Desinger**，it's a plug-in unit to  visualize your operation.
  I'm using `GridBagLayout` to format these panel,and here is an example.
   [This is the effect drawing adress](http://t1.qpic.cn/mblogpic/0e1a7240b53902bc7104/2000.jpg.)

```
public test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 685, 485);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{175, 40, 180, 217, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{15, 58, 220, 49, 55, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    JPanel gamepanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_gamepanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_gamepanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_gamepanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_gamepanel.gridheight = 2;
    gbc_gamepanel.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc_gamepanel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_gamepanel.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(gamepanel, gbc_gamepanel);
    gamepanel.setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 3;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_panel.gridheight = 3;
    gbc_panel.gridx = 3;
    gbc_panel.gridy = 2;
    contentPane.add(panel, gbc_panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_textField.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 4;
    contentPane.add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 2;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 4;
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);
}
```

If you want the GUI can be resizable,you can set the `weghitx` and `weghity` properties.

Comment: wow thx for the code, tho could you explain some of the parts like the gridx, gridy and the gbc_panel.fill and how do those kinda affect the panel in general.

Comment: well，i'm not good at English. So i just explain it as much as i can.`gridx` means the location of row,`gridy`means the location of column.`gbc_panel`.fill means Stretch the component in horizontal or vertical way.

Comment: BTW-can you understand Chinese?

Comment: This code is not written well. You recreate `GridBagConstraints` instead of reusing it. You also set sizes instead of letting the layout manager decide how to handle it.

Comment: @user1803551: I agree with your comment about setting sizes but not with the one about re-using the GBC. Most tutorials that I've seen on this subject recommend creating GBC's anew each time to avoid unknowingly carrying over an unwanted state. Myself, I usually create a static method, something like `public GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int  y, int w, int h)` to create a GBC for each component insertion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have never seen a tutorial or example that creates a new GBC for each component, but i will take your word on that and retract my complaint in the matter.

Comment: @user1803551: I found my source, it was the [Oracle GridBagLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Scroll down or search for the Specifying Constraints section where you'll find the quote `"However, it is recommended that you do not reuse GridBagConstraints, as this can very easily lead to you introducing subtle bugs if you forget to reset the fields for each new instance."`